# Как правильно называется деревянный поддон: паллет, палет, паллета, палета

Tags: этимология, орфография, грамотная-речь

Есть такая штука - деревянный поддон для хранения перевозки товаров. Известен ГОСТ на него - [ГОСТ 9557-87](http://docs.cntd.ru/document/1200023509)

Постоянно слышу/вижу его обозначение: паллет, паллета, палет, палета - (калька с английского *pallet*).

Причем версии кочует не только в сети, но также и в достаточно серьезных книгах/монографиях по логистике.

Внимание вопрос: какой из вариантов правильный? Желательно ссылку на верифицируемый источник ([википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD) не предлагать).

Comment: Думаю, здесь все доступно написано: [Разница между поддоном и паллетом](http://thedifference.ru/chem-otlichaetsya-poddon-ot-palleta/#h2_2)

Comment: Да, написано доступно, но не совсем понятно и логично. Из статьи можно сделать вывод: пустая тара - паллет ( мужской род);  тара с грузом - паллета ( женский род). Как же так? Неужели род существительного в русском языке зависит от того - нагрузят его или не нагрузят?

Comment: Так там и говорится, что в некоторых ситуациях тару с грузом называют паллетой.  Т. е. все зависит от языковых традиций коллектива. из статьи можно сделать вывод, что эти слова обозначают один и тот же предмет.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова там, в "статье" вообще нет рассуждений о грамматическом роде и нагрузке. Обсуждается разница между поддоном и "паллетом" и утверждается, что её нет.  "Паллета" по их орфографии - это не другое использование, это другое слово, **комплект** из "паллета" и груза.  . К орфографии вообще - никаким боком. А написание "паллет(а)" стоит признать ошибочным в любом случае. Колебание в грамматическом роде вполне возможно (можем обсудить конкретно), но вот удвоенной букве неоткуда взяться.

Answer (score 2):

Фиксации пока нет. В значении "поддон" логично **палета** (нем. Palette) 
Посмотрите обсуждение [тут](http://pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/3405390.html). Там ссылки на вполне верифицируемые источники.

У Лопатина "палета" - это, наверное, другое, от английского/французского pallete (палитра; сетка линий). Оно, как более старое, и представлено.

Comment: pallete в совремннном английском и французском невозможно в принципе. Только ***palette*** - во всех языках. А вот про два значения - это интересно. Только не думаю, что художественное - более старое. Кстати, они к одному корню восходят, палитра - это и есть поддон. И фиксация есть, посмотрите в других ответах. Несмотря на некоторую сумбурность вашей мысли, ответ нравится

Answer (score 1):

**[Палета](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD)**: ж. р., одна буква «л» согласно «Русскому орфографическому словарю» РАН. Паллета — ошибочный вариант.

**[Большой толковый словарь](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0&all=x)**

ПАЛЕТА, -ы; ж. [франц. palette - поддон]. Настил в виде плиты, щита для пакетной транспортировки грузов и т.п.; поддон.